# No internet connection after pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7

Tags: networking, shortcut-keys, internet

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Then I saw a black screen and then I restarted and logged back in. Everything seems fine but I have no internet connection anymore.

I do have internet on my other device. On wired settings it confirms that I am indeed connected. I am able to log into my router.

Ive tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> but it didn't solve the problem. I've searched online but I couldn't find a solution. I must admit though that I have little knowledge and don't really know what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: Apparently all was fixed by turning the VPN off and turning it back on again. I don't understand why, but my problem is fixed.